# How to map a variable taken in query to a gridview column in asp.net?

Tags: development, asp.net, sql-server

I have written a query in SQL server 2008 R2 and it is:

```
select *, Row_Number() Over(Order By Total_Marks DESC) as Rank
from tbl_Ranking_System 
order by Rank
```

In this query, I have taken variable called "Rank" and I am getting the value as expected. Now I am trying to map this Rank to a Column I have taken in the gridview. I am not able to see any value in the Rank column in the gridview. But when i execute in back end i am able to see the result. Please help me in mapping this Rank to the gridview column Rank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have a GridView with at least single column Rank as shown below

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HeaderStyle-BackColor="CornflowerBlue" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" CellPadding="5">
         <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Rank" HeaderText="Rank" />
        </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

On the page load, you could prepare a query, fetch the results and bind them with the gridview.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable dt;
        String SQL = "SELECT *, Row_Number() Over(Order By Total_Marks DESC) AS Rank FROM tbl_Ranking_System ORDER BY Rank";


        string sConstr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sConstr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(SQL, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comm))
                {
                    dt = new DataTable("tbl");
                    da.Fill(dt);
                }
            }
        }

        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```